# Why doesn't my Info.plist work?

Tags: ios, swift3, info.plist

The project is not recognising the Info.plist correctly.

For example, I want to use the camera or the photo library in the app and even though I added the keys to the Info.plist, I see an error indicating that I need to add those keys.

Recently I used a URL in the app and added `App Transport Security Settings` to `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and the app shows me an error for this too.

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the Info.plist as XML please? You can do this in Xcode by right clicking it and selecting Open As… > Source Code

Comment: In the folder where you have entire project, just check if there is any other .plist file.